# Laravel web socket not working on production server

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I am trying to use Laravel for websocket server with orchid/socket pakage. It works fine with running following command on the local :

```
php artisan socket:serve
```

But when I move my code to production web server it return 404 error.
Is above command to be executed on the server? 
Is it possible to running websocket at the same port with main web server?

Comment: Same here, did you solve it?